# Print elements of list using index from another list in python

Tags: python, loops, printing

I have the following variables with value assignments.

```
data_row=["Summary","Description","Date","comment","comment","comment"]
summary_column=0
comment_colomn=[3,4,5]
```

I need to print only summery and comments fields as follow.

```
Summery comment comment comment
```

I tried this with the following code, but it doesn't give the output correctly.

```
print(data_row[summary_column]+" ".join([data_row(clmn) for clmn in comment_column]))
```

Comment: You have a typo in the last list of your code `comment_colomn`, where as in your print you have `... comment_column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension to get a list of the comment columns:

```
[data_row[i] for i in comment_colomn]
```

and then add this to a list of the summary...

```
data_row=["Summary","Description","Date","comment","comment","comment"]
summary_column=0
comment_colomn=[3,4,5]

print([data_row[summary_column]] + [data_row[i] for i in comment_colomn])
```

```
['Summary', 'comment', 'comment', 'comment']
```

You can also modify this to print your output using join...

```
print(" ".join([data_row[summary_column]] + [data_row[i] for i in comment_colomn]))
```

```
Summary comment comment comment
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the follow code snippet:

```
data_row=["Summary","Description","Date","comment","comment","comment"]
summary_column = 0
comment_column = [3,4,5]

print([data_row[summary_column]] + [data_row[i] for i in comment_column])
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use this with that data_row[summary_column] part
1>

```
for i in comment_colomn:
    print(data_row[i])
```

2> `print(data_row[summary_column]+" ".join([data_row[clmn] for clmn in comment_colomn]))`
you had some syntax errors in your past code thats why it was not working.List indexs are not callable with these "()" but these "[]"